# python regex match after mixed characters string 'E(RHF) = '

Tags: python, regex, special-characters

How can I grep the value after a mixed characters expression like:

```
E(XXX) =  -305.5
```

using regular expressions?

```
for line in f:
   if (re.findall(r"E\(.{3}\) = -\d*\.\d*", line)):
     print(line)
```

Comment: Whst do you mean by "the entire expression"? To the end of the line? And does the line start with the `#`-Symbol if it appears?

Comment: have you attempted a regex for the entire expression after #? Does the second expression not work, what are you expecting?

Comment: @depperm nope the expression given does not work :( and i don't know why

Comment: @depperm, it only works if i look for SCF Done, then it just finds the line, but i can't seem to be able to extract the value. The full line in the file is `SCF Done:  E(RHF) =  -75.5859595965     A.U. after   10 cycles`

Comment: Try something like [`r'\bE\([A-Z]+\)(.*)'`](https://regex101.com/r/40zWDU/1) and use it with `re.search(r'\bE\([A-Z]+\)(.*)', s).group(1)` , see http://ideone.com/iibG7S

Comment: i tired the group thing before, always returns error. the expressions itself don't seem to grep anything..sorry for being such an incapable python beginner

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that some punctuation marks are specific for regular expressions. For example, `"."` matches anything, and `"("` is the start of a regex group. To avoid this, add backslash to them, like `"\."` and `"\("`. You could try something like this:

```
import re

re.findall(r"E\(.{3}\) = -\d*\.\d*", test_string)
```

And for the hashtag:

```
re.findall(r"# .*", test_string)
```

Comment: Please, clarify input and desired output. It will help me help you.